# Voice(Speech) Recognition in Spanish

Tags: android, speech-recognition

I am working in speech recognition API of android.

I am new in Speech Recognition Api and My requirement is as
Speech in Spanish and get best match text in also Spanish from Speech Recognition API of Android.
So,
Please! let me know if have you any solution about this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, "es-ES");

etc.....
```

Comment: hello thanks for your post
but i get results strings is in english of best match instands of spanish.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean?

Comment: the given code i allready implement and get result string from Recognizerintent's data is in english not in spanish.

Comment: look bellow my Code

Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, "es");
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE,
"es");
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_ONLY_RETURN_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE,"es");
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT,"Please start speaking...");
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 5);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);

Comment: @TejaDroid - Can you edit your question with this code please and also add how you are viewing the results and comment where the problem of English occurs. I'll take a look then